# Unit/Integration tests for DAL and BLL (with lambdas)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, integration-testing, data-access-layer

My code basically looks like this:

Data access contract:

```
public interface IProvideDataAccess<T>
    where T : Entity
{
    IEnumerable<T> Select(Func<T, bool> condition);
    void Save(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
}
```

Data access layer:

```
public class Db4oProvider<T> : IProvideDataAccess<T>
    where T : Entity
{
    private IEmbeddedConfiguration _configuration;
    private string _connectionString;

    public Db4oAccesDonnees(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
        _configuration = Db4oEmbedded.NewConfiguration();
    }

    IEnumerable<T> IProvideDataAccess<T>.Select(Func<T, bool> condition)
    {
        using (IObjectContainer db = Db4oEmbedded.OpenFile(_configuration, _connexion))
        {
            return db.Query<T>(e => condition(e));
        }
    }
    void IProvideDataAccess<T>.Save(T entity)
    {
        using (IObjectContainer db = Db4oEmbedded.OpenFile(_configuration, _connexion))
        {
            db.Store(entity);
        }
    }
    void IProvideDataAccess<T>.Delete(T entity)
    {
        using (IObjectContainer db = Db4oEmbedded.OpenFile(_configuration, _connexion))
        {
            db.Delete(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Business logic layer:

```
public class MyRepository
{
    protected IProvideDataAccess<MyEntityType> _dataAccessProvider;

    public MyRepository(IProvideDataAccess<MyEntityType> dataAccessProvider)
    {
        _dataAccessProvider = dataAccessProvider;
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyEntityType> SelectValidEntities()
    {
        return _dataAccessProvider.Select(e => /* test if entity is valid */);
    }
}
```

Unit/Integration tests are fairly new to me and I'm not sure where to begin.

I *think* the logical thing to do would be to

- write integration tests for the DAL
- write unit tests for the BLL (with fake DAL)

I this correct?

My biggest problem is with the "select" method and its Func parameter. How do I test/mock that?

Basically, what tests should I write for these two classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `DAL` looks like the classes which never change... In my opinion creating a `UT` or `IT` on them is a waste of time. You should cover class's behavior like `Db4oProvider<T>` with a good Component/"large Integration"(not only the unit + DB) tests. I offer you to read about `Test Pyramid`([In Martin Fowler blog](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html) and [this good article](http://www.velocitypartners.net/blog/2014/01/28/agile-testing-the-agile-test-automation-pyramid/)). I like the following pyramid:

[image]

About the `Select` method:

In `Integration test`(unit + DB) you have to put data inside your DB(or keep a DB with data...), call `Select` with a condition, then verify that you've got the expected data.

In `Component test` you need to test it as a part of behavior under test, if the test succeed then every thing is alright...

In `UT` the tests are split into 2 types:

1.The tests where you verify the behaviour of the condition(lambda) you pass into `Select` method:(in this way you also verify that `Select` was called with the right parameters... In my examples I use `RhinoMocks`)

```
var fakeProvider = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IProvideDataAccess<Entity>>();

fakeProvider.Select(o => o.Id =="asdfg");

fakeProvider.AssertWasCalled(access => access.Select(Arg<Func<Entity, bool>>
            .Matches(func => func(new Entity()
            {
                Id = "asdfg"
            }))));
```

2.The tests where you verify caller method behaviour. In those tests you should configure your `DAL` to return something matter  the parameters are:

```
_selectResult = new List<Entity>();
fakeProvider.Stub(x => x.Select(Arg<Func<Entity, bool>>.Is.Anything))
            .Return(_selectResult);
```